# Prove properties of Expectation for multiple random variables.

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables where $Y = cX$ for some constant $c > 0$. Prove that $$E(Y) = cE(x)$$ and $$V(Y) = c^2 V(x)$$ where $E(Y)$ is the expectation of $Y$, $E(x)$ is the expectation of $X$, and $V(Y)$ and $V(x)$ are the variance of $Y$ and $X$ respectively.

I have a bit of a concept as of why this works. What I was thinking is that since we know that the $E(Y)$ is equal to the sum of $f(k)P(x=k)$ where $f(k)$ is some function (here $Y = cX$)

From here though I do not know where to go to prove this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first [prove expectation is linear](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearity_of_Expectation_Function) (proof is in the discrete case, but in the general case, its linearity of integrals, since expectation is just an integral).

Then, by linearity, prove $var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ (there is some algebra in the middle). Then, apply linearity and the definition of $Y$ to this to get the result.

Comment: In the proof of expectation being linear... How then do I get from that that E(y) = cE(x)? I see how the proof works but if I am moving the bE(y) over (from the proof) I would have -bE(y) = aE(x)  @Batman

Comment: When you prove expectation is linear, you have shown for any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and constants $a$ and $b$ that $E[aX+bY] = a E[X] + b E[Y]$. You can just take $b=0$ to get the fact that $E[aX] = a E[X]$.